# Laptop Internet-synced Time Jumps Ahead by 44 Hours After Closing Lid

Tags: ubuntu

I haven't been able to isolate a cause for this, but sometimes when I close the lid on my laptop, the system time will jump forward, usually 44 hours to be exact. It will still be in sync with the time in minutes and seconds, but somehow the hours are completely screwed up. Usually this happens when I'm transitioning networks as well, but the time jump happens immediately after I open the lid, before I connect to the other network. It doesn't happen consistently, so I can't figure out what cases cause this anomaly. What could cause this, and is there a way to stop it?